# getting and using an attribute in protractor tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, protractor

this question is probably pretty basic, but I don't have the right feel for angularjs and protractor yet, as I'm new to using this. This might therefore be an [XY problem kind of question](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). If that is the case, I'd be happy to know about this, and get a hint what to look for instead.

**Actual Question**

Say I want to test a slider, and wish to set the the slider-knob to the middle of that slider, to then compare the value the slider has to an expected value.

The slider might have a width that I do not know beforehand, so I'm wondering what the correct way is to get and use such an unknown value in a protractor test.

Do I wrap the `it(..)` statement into a promise that gets the desired value (for example via `getAttribute()`? or is there are better way to go on about this?

Comment: Please show code you practiced so far.

Comment: I might actually answer this question myself later, I've done some promise chaining, and while I'm not sure this is the most elegant way to solve the problem, it seems to work (and might be the intended way).
I'll put an update to this online later

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by just using promise chaining to work with the values. I don't like that I have to do this for every spec where I need the values, but it seems nice enough otherwise.

Example:

```
it('should test some stuff', () => {
    page.someElement.getAttribute('someAttribute').then(someAttribute => {
      // ... use someAttribute here ...
    });
});
```